# C++: Storing strings in linked list

Tags: c++, arrays, string, linked-list

(I've only used C++ recreationally, so forgive the noobish question.)

I want to write a simple spreadsheet program that works in the terminal (via ncurses). Mostly personal edification. I want to store the cells as linked lists so that I wouldn't have to reallocate a bunch of data every time I wanted to move or insert rows; each cell is a node in a linked list, which contains the cell's data. The data will consist of ASCII characters.

Relevant consideration: Naturally, some of these cells will have to be resized to accommodate more characters.

**Question: What datatype should I use to store the cell contents?**

Thoughts: I've never used std::string and am kinda skeptical of the idea after a rather sour experience trying to program in D :). But I'm certainly open to the possibility that they're not that bad. I was thinking of using char arrays[], which fit the bill pretty nicely and are consistent with my C intuition. I also stumbled upon the suggestion to use std::vector while looking through StackOverflow, which seems even better since they're easy to resize, but I fear that might be considered clumsy.

G'day and thankee much.

Comment: If you want a linked list you can look at `std::list`. And don't be scared of using `std::string`. It is both easier and safer than `char[]`.

Comment: Don't reinvent the wheel. Just use `std::string` and one of the [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container) class templates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are storing a "string", then `std::string` would be a starting point. These allow for resizing and only take up a little more space than a `char *` [which you'd have to use if you want to resize the string - and you do want to load that file that has lines longer than X - no matter what X is, right?]. In fact, in a typical implementation there's only 2 `size_t` variables above and beyond a pointer, and that's about it. And you probably need at least one of them to go along with your `char *` anyway to keep track of the length of the actual string and the size of the memory you have allocated for the string - since you don't want to be calling `new`, `strcpy` and `delete` every single time a string changes size - unless you are a real masochist. (Being a little bit masochistic is fine, that's part of being a software developer - if a little pain stops you, you probably will give up before you achieve anything)

In a text editor, you will be constantly inserting, splitting and removing parts of the string, so having those functions available in the `std::string` class. As well as the "keeping track of the memory for you".

Comment: Well, that pretty much explains it. Thank you kindly. :D